# How to build a parse tree of simple expressions

Tags: scala, parsing

Let's build a parser tree for simple expressions such as `3 - 4 * 5`, using `scala.util.parsing.combinator._`:

```
def expr: Parser[Any] = term ~ opt(("+"|"-") ~ expr)
def term: Parser[Any] = factor ~ opt(("*"|"/") ~ factor)
def factor: Parser[Any] = wholeNumber | "(" ~> expr <~ ")"
```

With `3 - 4 * 5`, the result tree is:

```
       expr
      / |  \
  term  -   expr
   |       / |  \
 factor term * term  
   |      |      |
 number factor factor
   |      |      |
   3    number number
          |      |
          4      5
```

which is right. But with `3 - 4 + 5` my tree doesn't seem to correct:

```
       expr
      / |  \
  term  -   expr
   |       / |  \
 factor term + term  
   |      |      |
 number factor factor
   |      |      |
   3    number number
          |      |
          4      5
```

How can I fix that? I thought this was solution:

`def expr: Parser[Any] = expr ~ opt(("+"|"-") ~ term)`

but it's way too wrong...

**My full code**:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._


class Expr

case class Number(value: Int) extends Expr {
    override def toString = s"$value"
}

case class Operator(left: Expr, right: Expr, f: (Int, Int) => Int) extends Expr {
    override def toString = s"($f, $left, $right)"
}

class SimpleLanguageParser extends JavaTokenParsers {

    def expr: Parser[Expr] = (term ~ opt(("+" | "-") ~ expr)) ^^ {
        case a ~ None => a
        case a ~ Some("+" ~ b) => Operator(a, b, _ + _)
        case a ~ Some("-" ~ b) => Operator(a, b, _ - _)
    }

    def term: Parser[Expr] = (factor ~ opt(("*" | "/" ) ~ term)) ^^ {
        case a ~ None => a
        case a ~ Some("*" ~ b) => Operator(a, b, _ * _)
        case a ~ Some("/" ~ b) => Operator(a, b, _ / _)
    }

    def factor: Parser[Expr] = wholeNumber ^^ (n => Number(Integer.parseInt(n))) | "(" ~> expr <~ ")"

}

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        val parser = new SimpleLanguageParser
        val result = parser.parse(parser.expr, "3 - 4 + 5")
        println(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new Scala parser combinator library, so might not be able to answer your question :( but just out of curiosity, what's your expected result?

Comment: it supposes to be ((3 - 4) + 5), mine is (3 + (4 - 5))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `term ~ opt(("+"|"-") ~ expr)` couldn't reserve the order of +/- operations.

```
def largerExpr: Parser[Any] = expr ~ opt(("+"|"-") ~ expr)
def expr: Parser[Any] = term ~ opt(("+"|"-") ~ term)
```

EIDT

```
def expr1: Parser[Expr] = (expr ~ opt(("+" | "-") ~ expr)) ^^ {
    case a ~ None => a
    case a ~ Some("+" ~ b) => Operator(a, b, _ + _)
    case a ~ Some("-" ~ b) => Operator(a, b, _ - _)
}

def expr: Parser[Expr] = (term ~ opt(("+" | "-") ~ term)) ^^ {
    case a ~ None => a
    case a ~ Some("+" ~ b) => Operator(a, b, _ + _)
    case a ~ Some("-" ~ b) => Operator(a, b, _ - _)
}
```

Your result would be `(<function2>, 3, (<function2>, 4, 5))`, the result using `expr1` is `(<function2>, (<function2>, 3, 4), 5)`

Comment: your solution only parse (3 - 4) and skip (+ 5). I added my full script above just in case you're interested...

Comment: @HuyVo Did it? I tested it before posting an answer. I'll try with your code anyways.

Comment: Thank you, it was my mistake (I forgot to change at `val result = parser.parse(parser.expr, "3 - 4 + 5")`). It works perfect :D

Comment: @HuyVo It was a good chance to try Scala parsing combinator! :-)